# Use (weak or strong) law of large numbers to show integrals converge

Tags: probability, integration, uniform-distribution, law-of-large-numbers

Take a look at the question below

---

for $ $ $ $ $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb{R}$ continuous  :

show that  $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\idotsint_{0}^{1} f((x_{1} \cdot\cdot\cdot x_{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}) \,dx_1 \dots dx_n = f(\frac{1}{e})$$

---

solution:

Let $X_{i}\sim Uniform(0,1)$

One should assure themselves before we proceed that :

- *$f$ is bounded*
- $E(log(X_{i}))=-1$
- WLLN tells us (recalling the deff. of weak convergence) $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}E[f( \frac{S_{n}}{n})] = E[f(E(X_{i}))] $$ for $S_{n}=X_{1}+\cdot +X_{n} $ where $X_{i}$ are iid r.v with finite mean. And any continuous bounded function f.

Now we have
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\idotsint_{0}^{1} f((x_{1} \cdot\cdot\cdot x_{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}) \,dx_1 \dots dx_n $$
(by deff. of $X_{i}$ and the law of unconscious statistician)
$$ = \lim_{n\to \infty} E[f((X_{1} \cdot\cdot\cdot X_{n})^{\frac{1}{n}})  $$
$$ = \lim_{n\to \infty} E[f(e^{\frac{1}{n}(log(X_{1})+\cdots + log(X_{n}))})] $$
$$ = \lim_{n\to \infty} E[f(e^{\frac{S_{n}}{n}})] $$ (where $S_{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} log(X_{i}))$
$$ = \lim_{n\to \infty} E[f(e^{E(log(X_{i}))})] $$ (by WLLN and noting that f composed with e is still continuous (and bounded) on $(0,1)$)

$$ = f(\frac{1}{e}) $$ (since $E(log(X_{i}))=-1$ )

Does anyone know if i could use the same strategy to solve:

show that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\idotsint_{0}^{1} f(\frac{\,(x_1)^{2}+ \dots +(x_n)^{2}} {\,x_1+ \dots +x_n } ) \,dx_1 \dots dx_n = \frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: Seems like your question was truncated...

Comment: Yes I fixed it, just added something i had missed. :)

Comment: "Does anyone know if i could use the same strategy to solve:" Yes you could, and you would find the limit $$f\left(\frac23\right)$$

Comment: okay must be a typo in the question, ill have a think about how to go about this one.